# C Windows buffer size

Tags: c, windows, size, buffer, recv

In windows lets say i'm using the `recv` function to receive data from a socket.
I'm curious how big would an optimal buffer be? I could make it `1024` bytes or I could make it `51200` bytes, or bigger. I'm wondering which one would be better for performance.

This doesn't only apply to the `recv` function, lets say im reading a large text file, do i want a very large buffer, or a smaller buffer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

THe operating system performs its own buffering, so the size of your buffer does not really matter. the performance penalty lies in the function call: a 1 byte buffer will be inefficient because it will require too much calls to `recv()`. a buffer too big is just a waste of space.

an optimal size will be something like twice the size of the data you expect to receive or are able to process in a single `recv()` call, with a lower limit of approximately 1 or 2 tcp frame.

i personally use a 4KB buffer, but that's my own preference, and it depends largely on the application i am writing.

Answer (score 0):

The operating system buffers it already, so you might as well just read one byte at the time.

Comment: One context switch per byte isn't going to give you any "best of breed in performance awards"...

Answer (score 0):

This would depend on the kind of data you are expecting and the protocol you expecting.
UDP for example would give you a whole packet in one go so an optimal buffer size could be 1500.

The real performance impediment would be the function call (`recv` in this case) that you will make. To improve performance, you could start with a default large value and then analyze the packet sizes being received. Based on the analysis, you could pass an (almost) "ideal" buffer size.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a server-type situation where you don't know what services are to be run on it, you could use an array of buffer pools of varying sizes, eg [128,1024,4096,16384,65536].  When something connects, use a 128 size and, if all 128 come in, use 1024 next time.. and so on.

On clients or servers with a known protocol/loading, just sorta guess at it, (much as suggested by the other posters :)

Rgds,
Martin